# Access Eclipse built in server in host from VIrtualBox guest OS.

Tags: eclipse, gwt, networking, jetty, virtualbox

Im developing a GWT application in Eclipse on OSX, using the built in Jetty server.

I would like to access: http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 from 
my guest OS (win7) in VirtualBox.

I can access my Tomcat server from guest using the hosts ip-address. Ex: http://192.168.0.199:8080/MyApp.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Add the bindaddress to your launch code:

```
-bindAddress 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: If it works, please mark this answer aas correct and close ths question.

Comment: Where does this go? Can you explain how to use this option?